# Adapt size of a group of composable

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm quite new in mobile dev and Compose, so my question is probably trivial, but here's my problem.

I have a screen with an image and a text at top of the screen.
At the bottom, I have a button.

In the middle, I show some texts, an image,...
As this group of datas is used in another screen, I've created a function which contains those composable elements. But I don't find a way to get all the elements in this function adapt to the screen size.

My main screen

```
    Column(
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(backgroundGradient)
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        Image(
            [...]
        )

        //The function I call with several composable components
        ShowCurrentRound(currentGame.currentRound) 

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
        
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ },) {
            Text(text = "Next round")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
    }
```

My custom function

```
@Composable
fun ShowCurrentRound(round : GameRound) {

    Text(
        text = "Round ${$round.current}",
        color = Color.Black)
    
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
    
    //The image I want to expand depending the space left
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.roundPlaceholder),
        contentDescription = "Cover",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        modifier = Modifier
            .border(color = Color.Black, width = 1.dp)
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
    Text(
        text = "${round.title}",
        color = Color.Black,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
    )
}
```

Thank you for your help!

It works fine when in main function, but not when composables are built in the function.

I've tried the different contentScale available, on both screens. But can't figure out how to search this problem, as I don't have the good vocabulary for Compose yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of a [`weight`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/ColumnScope#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).weight(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Boolean)) Modifier provided in the [`Column`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#Column(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement.Vertical,androidx.compose.ui.Alignment.Horizontal,kotlin.Function1)) Composable.

The `weight` Modifier allows to evenly distribute the available space in a `Column`. If you only set `weight` on one child of a `Column`, it will take up all available space.

In your case, you will have to apply the `weight` Modifier on two places:

First, add a `Column` to the `ShowCurrentRound` Composable and set a `weight` on the `Image`. Add another parameter to the function that allows passing in a Modifier:

```
@Composable
fun ShowCurrentRound(modifier: Modifier, round: GameRound) {

    Column(modifier = modifier) {

        Text(
            text = "Round ${$round.current}",
            color = Color.Black)
    
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
    
        //The image I want to expand depending the space left
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.roundPlaceholder),
            contentDescription = "Cover",
            contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)  // set weight here
                .border(color = Color.Black, width = 1.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = "${round.title}",
            color = Color.Black,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )
    }
}
```

Then, in your parent Composable, call the `ShowCurrentRound` Composable like this:

```
//...
ShowCurrentRound(Modifier.weight(1f), currentGame.currentRound)
//...
```

This will make the `ShowCurrentRound` Composable take up all available space, and make the Image take up all available space within `ShowCurrentRound` Composable.

---

If you want to save yourself the Column within `ShowCurrentRound`, you can also do it like this:

```
@Composable
fun ColumnScope.ShowCurrentRound(round : GameRound) {  // note the ColumnScope extension
    
 Text(
        text = "Round ${$round.current}",
        color = Color.Black)
    
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))
    
    //The image I want to expand depending the space left
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.roundPlaceholder),
        contentDescription = "Cover",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
        modifier = Modifier
            .weight(1f)
            .border(color = Color.Black, width = 1.dp)
    )
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
    Text(
        text = "${round.title}",
        color = Color.Black,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
    )

}
```

However, with this approach you may only call the `ShowCurrentRound` Composable within a `Column` Composable.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I knew the existence of the weight parameter, but dit not think about passing the modifier like this. It works perfectly!